# ScrollLeft not working in conjunction with "if" statements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been attempting to create a small sliding part operate by two `<div>` elements at either side of this particular page element using jQuery's `scrollLeft`. Everything initially seemed to work as intended - despite what some people would call incredibly poor practise being involved and likely with some incredibly primitive code.
Trying to make the element easier to use I decided to include an if statement in order to cause the images to loop back round to the first if the button was clicked more times than images that existed.

Essentially the code worked as follows (where each image is 100 pixels wide)

```
$("#next").click(function() {
  position = position + 100;
    $("#wrap").animate({ 
        scrollLeft: ( position )
    });
});
```

but ceased to work when changed to

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    if (positon < 300){
       position = position + 100;
       $("#wrap").animate({ 
          scrollLeft: ( position )
       });
    } else {
        loopBack();
        }
});
```

where `loopBack` is a function that sets `position` to 0 and proceeds as per the initial (working) function.
JSHint reports no issues with the code syntax itself and I have changed the value check to `position != 300` to see what difference this made (none, as it so turns out).

The JSFidde can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/ActualRealJamz/8WcUb/7/
The backward function has been kept as per original so that you may see how it was initially working and `wrap` has has x-axis scrolling enabled so that it's actually possible to use the backward function.

I'm really stuck for ideas here and any help would be most appreciated here.

Comment: What does `position` contain at the beginning of the function? Is it a (gulp!) global variable?

Comment: "Uncaught ReferenceError: **positon** is not defined "

Comment: Also I think you need to be checking for `200`, not `300`, as there are only 3 blocks. Otherwise there'll be an extra click required to slide back to 0.

Comment: what @Pointy said and also wrap entire back click with `if (position > 0)`  [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/8WcUb/10/)

Comment: @lucke84 judging by the tone of your comment you're likely to hate me for this but: yes. It is set to 0 for initial scroll placement.

Comment: @Pointy ah, thanks for that. My mistake - completely missed that.

Comment: Global variables are not necessarily bad, but you have to sure how to use them. Not hating you for this :)

Comment: @lucke84 Oh, thank god. I thought I had gotten into a bad practice. Yeah, it didn't really make sense to have the variable in a single function, when two required access. Out of interest: is there any way to make a variable that is not global accessible by a select few functions. I can't think of any practical use for it - other than for personal intrigue.

Comment: Let me put it this way: if you're not aware of which might be the dangers of using global variable, consider it a bad practice :)

Comment: Heh, thanks: I'll bear it in mind in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo in your code.

This is easy to spot if you check the console logs:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: positon is not defined

Corrected code (posit **i** on)

```
$("#next").click(function() {
    if (position < 300){
       position = position + 100;
       $("#wrap").animate({ 
          scrollLeft: ( position )
       });
    } else {
        loopBack();
        }
});
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I completely missed that. Makes me feel a little embarrassed, to say the least!